# Python writing to file same amount of bytes

Tags: python, io, pcap, packet-sniffers

I was trying to write Pcap generator and I want to write fixed length of bytes to file. Frame length that I sniff is always changeable obviously but I should also define this length in Pcap packet header. I set it as 1500 bytes. Is there any way to put leading zeros to byte object that complete it to 1500 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bytes.zfill`.

```
>>> bs = bytes([1, 2, 3])
>>> bs
b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>> padded = bs.zfill(10)
>>> padded
b'0000000\x01\x02\x03'
```

This is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.zfill) for `bytes.zfill`:

> `bytes.zfill(width)`
>
> `bytearray.zfill(width)`
>
> Return a copy of the sequence left filled with ASCII `b'0'` digits to make a sequence of length `width`. A leading sign prefix (`b'+'`/ `b'-'`
>   is handled by inserting the padding after the sign character rather
>   than before. For `bytes` objects, the original sequence is returned if
>   width is less than or equal to `len(seq)`.